# Printing contents of multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am getting following complex arrays from database, I need individual record like below in each iteration (loop).

```
subscribed_store -> Name

subscribed_companyLogo -> logo image

subscribed_merchant -> Company Name
```

How can we simplify following.

```
/********************** First Iteration *******************/
Array
(
    [subscribed_store] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 55
                    [name] => test

                )

        )

    [subscribed_companyLogo] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://test.com/images/logo.png
        )

    [subscribed_merchant] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [company_name] => Google
                    [company_url] => http://www.google.com
                    [first_name] => David
                )

        )

)
```

Thanks a Lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `$array` holding the above array then try

```
echo $array["subscribed_store"][0]->name;

echo $array["subscribed_companyLogo"][0];

echo $array["subscribed_merchant"][0]->company_name;
```

if you want it in dynamic way then see below

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val)
{
    foreach($val as $subkey=>$subval)
    {
        echo $subval->id;
    }
}
```

this code will work globally and will echo id. but you need to echo different element which are different keys. so use the followings

```
foreach($array["subscribed_store"] as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $val->name;
}



foreach($array["subscribed_companyLogo"] as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $val;
}



foreach($array["subscribed_merchant"] as $key=>$val)
{
    echo $val->company_name;
}
```

Comment: Great!, but it prints only one row, and I want it in loop.

Comment: ok then check my edited answer. I'm editing it.

Comment: @Bheem which part is dynamic? [0] - this part?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $array is the array in the question,

```
 <table>

<tr>
<td> Store </td>
<td> Company Logo </td>
<td> Company Name </td>
</tr>

<?php

foreach($array as $key => $row)
{
 ?>
<tr>
<td> <?php echo $row['subscribed_store'][0]->name;?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $row['subscribed_companyLogo'][0];?> </td>
<td> <?php echo $row['subscribed_merchant'][0]->company_name;?> </td>
</tr>
<?php

}


?>
</table>
```